# How to remove Highlight (<mark>) from a paragraph using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have HTML where some paragraphs contain `<mark>` elements. This causes the text within the `<mark>` element to be highlighted. Essentially, I want to remove the highlight by removing the `<mark>` element but keeping the textContent.

What's the best way to do this?

Here's an example paragraph:

[image: Example with highlighted text]

I want to remove the highlighted text. The HTML contains `<span>` and other elements and some `<mark>` elements that I don't want removed. The ones I want removed have a class of .show-mark. I know how to find just the `<mark>` elements that I want to remove but I don't know how to remove them.

Here's the HTML for the example paragraph:

```
<p id="p85" class="cmiTranPara note-style-bookmark note-style-bookmark-start note-style-bookmark-end">
<i class="playmark play icon"></i>
<i class="timing large circular red clock icon"></i>
<span class="pnum has-annotation" data-aid="1574791210024">(p85)&nbsp;</span>
Miracle-mindedness is still a stage of perception just short of
<mark class="show-mark">master</mark>y. For 
<mark class="show-mark">master</mark>y comes when you know that you are literally and deliberately creating. And there is nothing miraculous about it. You will decree a thing and it shall be so!
</p>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please may you share an HTML/JS [mcve]? Are there other elements mixed in too, like `span` or `em`? --- A very quick an naive way would be to replace the textContent `myElement.textContent = myElement.textContent` (this will remove _any_ element inside `myElement`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
targets = document.querySelectorAll("mark");
for (let target of targets) {  
  target.outerHTML=target.innerHTML;
}
```

and see if it works.